# How to serialize object into Soap XML format

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, .net-core

I am calling a WCF service and passing some input values that give me output values as a response. I am doing with the demo requests in the string format. but I need to make it more dynamic so I am thinking to serialize an object into Soap XML format but I don't know how to do that.

```html
public void callservice()
{
string reqdata = "<MSRequest>"+
@"<RequestData id="TESTING">"+
@"<Attributes>"+
@"<attribute key="ProductID">534</attribute>"+
@"<attribute key="AGE">29</attribute>"+
@"<attribute key="Gender">0</attribute>"+
"</Attributes>"+
"<RequestOutput>"+
@"<attribute key="ProductName" />"+
@"<attribute key="Premiumamount" />"+
"</RequestOutput>"+
"</RequestData>"+
"</MSRequest>";

Product.Productservice service = new Product.Productservice();
var response = service.processrequest(reqdata);

}
```

//Above is the code I am using. As you guys can see I am passing a string with hardcoded values. But I want to serialize into soap XML that will serialize objects into a given below format.

```html
<attribute key="ProductID">534</attribute>
```

Comment: You can use the SoapFormatter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter?view=netframework-4.8 ... this helps you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
        public void callservice()
        {

            string id = "TESTING";
            string productID = "534";
            int age = 29;
            int gender = 0;

            XElement reqData = new XElement("MSRequest", new object[] {
                new XElement("RequestData", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("id", id),
                    new XElement("Attributes", new object[] {
                        new XElement("attribute", new object[] {
                            new XAttribute("key", "ProductID"),
                            productID,
                        }),
                        new XElement("attribute", new object[] {
                            new XAttribute("AGE", "ProductID"),
                            age,
                        }),
                        new XElement("attribute", new object[] {
                            new XAttribute("key", "Gender"),
                            gender,
                        })
                    }),
                    new XElement("RequestOutput", new object[] {
                        new XElement("attribute", new object[] {
                            new XAttribute("key", "ProductName")
                        }),
                        new XElement("attribute", new object[] {
                            new XAttribute("AGE", "Premiumamount")
                        })
                    })
                })
            });


            Product.Productservice service = new Product.Productservice();
            var response = service.processrequest(reqData.ToString());
```

---

For serialization use following classes :

```
    public class MSRequest
    {
        [XmlElement("RequestData")]
        public List<RequestData> requestData { get; set; }
    }
    public class RequestData
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Attributes")]
        [XmlArrayItem("attribute")]
        List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
    }
    public class Attribute
    {
        [XmlAttribute("key")]
        public string key { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you jdweng.This is exactly how I wanted.

Comment: if I want to implement this in domain class how it can be done?

Comment: Not sure of your question.  The code can be used in any class project.

Comment: I want to create a class and serialize it in a format I mentioned below.       <MSRequest>
<RequestData id="TESTING">
<Attributes>
<attribute key="ProductID">534</attribute>
<attribute key="AGE">29</attribute>

Comment: I update code to include classes for serialization.